# How to SendAndSave email with EWS with windows auth and identity without a mailbox?

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

My scenario is this:

- I connect to Exchange Web Services (EWS) using a service account and windows authentication
- I don't use Impersonation
- The service account doesn't have a mailbox
- I connect to a mailbox 'MyMailbox' to read and send emails. Whenever I send emails I use `SendAndSaveCopy()`, specifying MyMailbox's SentItems folder to save in. Without specifying the folder `SendAndSaveCopy()` fails, understandably, as there's no mailbox linked to my service account where it could save the email.
- I sometimes want to Send As or Send On Behalf Of another user, so I set the `From` property to that other user's primary SMTP address for that.

In this scenario things work fine until I send an email with an attachment. In that case it fails with `ResponseCode = ErrorMissingEmailAddress` and `MessageText = When making a request as an account that does not have a mailbox, you must specify the mailbox primary SMTP address for any distinguished folder Ids.`

Looking at the SOAP message that's sent from my `SendAndSaveCopy()` I can see it's quite different when I have an attachment - note the `MessageDisposition="SaveOnly"`

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Header>
      <t:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2010_SP2" />
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
      <m:CreateItem MessageDisposition="SaveOnly">
        <m:Items>
          <t:Message>
            <t:Subject>My test email subject</t:Subject>
            <t:Body BodyType="HTML">....
```

whereas when sending without an attachment it has `<m:CreateItem MessageDisposition="SendAndSaveCopy">`. It seems reasonable that EWS is first saving the email and then it'll send it. Indeed the [API doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd634248%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) says

> This method does not work if the message has unsaved attachments. In that case, the message must first be saved and then sent.

Although `SendAndSaveCopy()` seems to work fine when I'm connecting as an identity that has a mailbox, and [MSDN example code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh532564(v=exchg.80).aspx) shows calling `SendAndSaveCopy()` without any interim steps. The example specifically says that `SendAndSaveCopy()` results in three calls to EWS: CreateItem, CreateAttachment, SendItem.

My main question is: how should I call EWS to achieve the same thing as `SendAndSaveCopy()` but when I have an attachment?

A secondary question: is this a bug? Shouldn't `SendAndSaveCopy()` when given a folderId use that folder for the CreateItem call?

I'm using EWS 15.0.0.0 and specifying Exchange2010_SP2 api version.

UPDATE:

On further inspection I see that EWS Managed API is also issuing multiple EWS calls for `SendAndSaveCopy()` when there are attachments and I'm using username & password auth. I see two EWS messages:

- The first has `<m:CreateItem MessageDisposition="SaveOnly">` and notably *no* `SavedItemFolderId`. So where is it saved!? My guess is it's saved to a default location for the current user's mailbox, which fails for my windows auth scenario because there's no current user's mailbox.
- The response from this provides the ItemId for the saved mail message and its saved attachment.
- The second EWS call has `<m:SendItem SaveItemToFolder="true">` and also sets the `SavedItemFolderId`

I still feel like this is a bug or missing feature from `SendAndSaveCopy()`: it should use the specified folder location to save the temp message. But in any case, what EWS Managed API calls *should* I use to get the desired effect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> > The first has  and notably no SavedItemFolderId. So where is it saved!? My guess is it's saved to a default location for the current user's mailbox, which fails for my windows auth scenario because there's no current user's mailbox.

The default save location is the Draft Folder of a Mailbox who's security principal you are using. EWS is a client API so the behaviours you see are designed around what you would expect a normal Email client to do.

If you want to send a Message with an Attachment without the intermediate step you can MIME encode the message you want to send with the attachment and then send it with one call eg.

```
EmailMessage test2 = new EmailMessage(service);
String bodyContent = "<html><head><meta http-equiv=\"Content-type\" content=\"text/html;charset=UTF-8\">Hello World</head><body></body></html> ";

CDO.Message msMessage = new CDO.Message();
msMessage.BodyPart.Charset = "UTF-8";
msMessage.HTMLBody = bodyContent;
msMessage.HTMLBodyPart.Charset = "UTF-8";
msMessage.AddAttachment("c:\\temp\\Document.docx");
ADODB.Stream asMessageStream = msMessage.GetStream();
asMessageStream.Type = ADODB.StreamTypeEnum.adTypeBinary;
byte[] bdBinaryData1 = new byte[asMessageStream.Size];
bdBinaryData1 = (byte[])asMessageStream.Read(asMessageStream.Size);
service.TraceEnabled = true;
test2.MimeContent = new MimeContent("UTF-8", bdBinaryData1);
test2.ToRecipients.Add("user@domain.com");
test2.Subject = "test";
test2.SendAndSaveCopy();
```

Cheers
Glen

Comment: great, thanks @GlenScales. So if I want to mimic that default behaviour, kind-of, I'd use CreateItem and save to the mailbox's Drafts folder, then call SendItem and save to the SentItems folder? (i.e. instead of the code above to send in one go, which isn't a particular requirement)

Comment: Sure that should work fine as long as the account being used has rights to the applicable folders